# Remove Class if .dropdown does not have .active -- jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is a horizontal menu on larger view ports and when you click the dropdown, the menu expands and the list is inline. There's a span that is appended to show the list in strip under the parent level. All works fine, except one thing because my jQuery skills are rather crappy-ish.

**The question is how to take this jQuery (work with this jQuery) and only remove the class .menu-open off the html if the .navbar-nav li.dropdown does NOT have the .active class but it also has to work with the existing stuff here so that when the user clicks outside the class is removed when it doesn't have the class .active and so forth. See the Bin link below.**

### This is the demo I have so far: http://jsbin.com/micugu/1/

*The best way to see what I mean is to visit this link above, click the page outside the navbar, and you'll see (if your page is wide enough) the behavior I'm trying to prevent.*

http://jsbin.com/micugu/1/edit

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function (a) {      
        if ($(a.target).parents().index($('.navbar-nav')) == -1){
               $('html').removeClass('menu-open');
        }      
});
```

and this:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function () {       
  if (!$(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {      
        $('html').addClass('menu-open');          
  } else {        
     $('html').removeClass('menu-open');      
  }        
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you were looking for

[Edited --> JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/vna3Lhmz/9/)

[Edited link to full screen result](http://jsfiddle.net/karthickj25/vna3Lhmz/9/embedded/result/)

this is the code i've used to achive the result.

```
$("li").click(function(e){  
     $("li[class *='active']").each(function(){
     $(this).removeClass('active');    
     });

    if(!$(this).hasClass('dropdown'))
    {
       $('html').removeClass('menu-open');
    }
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($(a.target).parents().index($('.navbar-nav')) == -1){
         $('html').removeClass('menu-open');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for trying. It is working the same way as before.

Comment: Hi.. in my jsFiddle the menu-open only applies to dropdown in active, for other menu it is removed.. i thought this is what you were looking for.

Comment: removed invalid link.

Comment: Thanks. The thing I'm trying to prevent is the bar from disappearing when the page is clicked, please look at yours or mine in a very wide screen.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you are looking for? http://jsbin.com/yuloqebe/1/edit?html,js,output

```
if (!$(".nav-bg").hasClass('active')){
    $('html').removeClass('menu-open');
}
```

basically if hasClass returns false we will remove the menu-open class

Comment: I updated the question so it was more clear. The question is how to take this jQuery (in question) and only remove the class .menu-open off the html if the .navbar-nav li.dropdown does NOT have the .active class.

Comment: that's what this does. hasClass returns false. The "!" at the beginning will make the statement equate to true

Comment: as i can see the .active class still sticks to the first dropdown and .open class code affecting to the removal and addition of .menu-open class... i think its conflicting with each other...also as Jonathan said, this is correct way...

Comment: Yep, it's effed up. I will fiddle with it more, I was getting so far then my brain couldn't deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I got you, you can Try something like this:

```
    if(!$('.dropdown.navbar-nav').hasClass('active')){
          $('.menu-open').removeClass('menu-open'); // will remove menu-open  class
        }
```

Comment: The question is how to take this jQuery and only remove the class .menu-open off the html if the .navbar-nav li.dropdown does NOT have the .active class.

Comment: and... how's the answer telling you anything different. Please mention.

Comment: It also has to keep the current script there that removes it if it is clicked outside and it's not the navbar-nav it's the navbar-nav dropdown. Thanks though

Comment: it removes the menu-open class wherever it is used.. just the class.. and only navbar-nav has the active class..

Comment: it's not about the repo... Sorry couldn't help :(

Comment: and please don't award anything, if it doesn't work for you, it's not worth any...